# Does sleep() affect pthread execution?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, sleep

I am confused about this example:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h> 

void *thread_func() 
{ 
    sleep(1); // removing this changes the result
    printf("\n");
    return NULL;
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
    {
        pthread_t tid; 
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, NULL); 
    }  

    pthread_exit(NULL); 
    return 0; 
}
```

if i run this with the `sleep(1)`, i count 2047 lines, without it 10000, as expected. What is going on here?

EDIT: Corrected number of expected lines to 10000.

Comment: Why would you expect 10000 threads, each printing a single blank line, to produce 3000 lines?

Comment: What do you think `pthread_exit(NULL);` does?

Comment: 10000 threads is an awful lot, are you sure `pthread_create()` isn't failing sometimes, due to hitting some limit?  You should be checking its return value to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside that the code shown tries to created 10000 threads which, if created successfully, would print 10000 lines not 3000, the core question is:

Why are less threads `print`ing if each thread waits 1s compared to not waiting?

Possible reasoning:

Each thread eats up resources. Due to this the maximum number of threads existing concurrently is limited.

If each thread waits for 1s before ending it can be assumed that the available resources are eaten up faster then if the thread exited immediately. So if resources are exhausted the thread's creation simply fails, which the code ignores, but just tries to create the next one.

To see what is really going on the code should log the case of failed creation like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <errno.h>

void *thread_func(void) 
{ 
    sleep(1); /* Removing this probably lowers the number of failed creations. */
    printf("\n");
    return NULL;
} 

int main(void) 
{ 
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
    {
        pthread_t tid; 
        if (errno = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, NULL))
        {
          perror("pthread_create() failed");
        }
    }  

    pthread_exit(NULL); 

    /* Never arriving here. */
    return 0; 
}
```

The number of lines printed by the above code is expected to be 10000 in total, with some lines being empty going to `stdout`, and some listing the creation failure going to `stderr`.

Comment: Yes thank you, this solves the mystery indeed. I never program in C, otherwise I'd probably have the instinct to check the error. When I do `./threads_corrected 2>&1 | grep -i failed | wc -l` ... i see the missing 7953 failed attempts!

Answer (score 2):

Since your program does not wait for its threads before it exits, what is happening is that it has a vaguely defined time to run before exiting the program destroys all of the threads.

Update: `pthread_exit` does wait for threads. For threads that are running. What I suspect is happening is that the threads created by `pthread_create` are not fully constructed before `pthread_exit` and then the program exits. Part of thread construction happens in the new thread, so if it never gets scheduled to run then that thread may as well not exist.

Creating 10,000 threads takes time. So does destroying them. In the meantime apparently 3,000 threads manage to reach the printf statement.

The amount of time and the number of prints is dependent on so many different factors that it may as well be random.

Comment: Leaving `main()` by calling `pthread_exit()` is not expected to end the process (as opposed to just `return`ing), but *only* the "main" thread.

Comment: Thank you for answering, your suspicion was correct of course. `pthread_create` failed. I chose the other answer because of the `perror` check.